# structopt: error[E0277]: the trait bound `String: From<&OsStr>`

Tags: rust, structopt

I'm using Rust's [`structopt` crate](https://docs.rs/crate/structopt/0.3.23), but when I try to compile examples I'm getting the following error,

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `String: From<&OsStr>` is not satisfied
   --> bin/seq.rs:21:36
    |
21  |     #[structopt(short, long, parse(from_os_str))]
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&OsStr>` is not implemented for `String`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <String as From<&String>>
              <String as From<&mut str>>
              <String as From<&str>>
              <String as From<Box<str>>>
            and 2 others
note: required by `from`
```

Comment: If it's taken out of the examples and doesn't compile, maybe it'd be a good idea to submit an issue to fix (or clarify) the examples in question? A SO post is great, but eliminating the source of the confusion sounds better.

Comment: @user4815162342 I think It's a typo/failed adaptation on my part. I can't find the original that I thought I copied pasted. Problem was me, still think this will help other people who do the same thing (copy the attributes and change the types in the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a [`String` into a `OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-7) with an infallible conversion, but you can not convert a `OsString` into a `String`.

This is because an `OsStr` accepts things that are not valid `Strings` so there is no way to ensure an `OsStr` that `structopt` parses into can be converted to a `String`.

You likely don't need to `parse()` at all,

```
#[structopt(short, long)]
```

Not

```
#[structopt(short, long, parse(from_os_str))]
```